# docker compose flask-sqlalchemy "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: python, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose file :

```
version: '3'

services:
    flask-app:
        container_name: flask-app
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '5001:5000'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        networks:
            - backend

    mysql-db:
        container_name: mysql-db
        image: mysql:8.0.23
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'users'
          MYSQL_USER: 'ray'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123456'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456'
        ports:
            - '3307:3306'
        volumes:
          - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
        platform: linux/amd64

networks:
    backend:

volumes:
    app:
    database:
```

and my app.py file had configuration to connect mysql-db :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
    os.getenv('DB_USER', 'ray'),
    os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
    os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307'),
    os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'users')
)
db.init_app(app)
```

and I got error like this :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: You may wish to check the `ports` argument, because you have [remapped the port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361128/how-to-connect-to-mysql-created-with-docker-to-another-port-not-port-3306).  Just change all the relevant ports to the default unless you have a good reason to remap them. Further [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338773/docker-host-port-and-container-port).

Comment: yes, there was something worry with my ports configuration, and I corrected it. I found as the configuration is right , remapped the posts is ok. I remapped the ports because I already used 5000 and 3306 port in local. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql is running in a container in the same network, you can access the other container services using the container name and the actual port that is being used.

Use `mysql-db:3306` as host and port instead of `localhost:3307`

Comment: got it , and I also checked and changed the docker file entrypoint. And it worked. Thank u very much! Hope you have a good day.

ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql-db:3307", "-t", "60", "--", "python", "app.py"]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the file and it worked. I post this for reference, in case someone got error like me.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    flask-app:
        container_name: flask-app
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '5001:5000'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        depends_on:
            - mysql-host

    mysql-host:
        container_name: mysql-db
        image: mysql:8.0.23
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'users'
          MYSQL_USER: 'ray'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123456'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        ports:
            - '3307:3306'
        volumes:
          - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
        platform: linux/amd64

volumes:
    app:
    database:
```

app.py (mysql configuration)

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
    os.getenv('DB_USER', 'ray'),
    os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
    os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'mysql-host'),
    os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'users')
)
```

docker file (configuration)

```
FROM python:3
#WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql-db:3307", "-t", "60", "--", "python", "app.py"]
```

Finally, thank you to the people above for their help : )